# Как включить бэкапы на proxmox на подключённом хранилище?

Tags: резервное-копирование, хранилище, proxmox

Исходные условия:

- есть сервер proxmox (4.2),
- на физическом сервере настроено два хранилища: ssd, на котором стоит гипервизор, hdd (в soft raid через mdadm) с настроенным LVM; оба хранилища подключены в proxmox.

Проблема: Proxmox даёт возможность создавать бэкапы только на хранилище на ssd, а места на нём естественно сильно меньше, чем на hdd.

Вопрос: Можно ли включить возможность хранения бэкапов на хранилище hdd?

Answer (score 1):

Так в настройках нужного хранилища добавьте содержимое VZDump

Comment: старайтесь не публиковать коментарий как ответ.

Comment: почему это комментарий? вполне себе рабочий ответ.

Comment: Недоступен флаг VZDump для LVM-дисков... Похоже надо будет переходить на другу ФС.